# Current thru two series resistors, 1 small, 1 large

Tags: home-experiment

I have a circuit that has series resistors for a switching regulator. Voltage is 6V. There's a "current sense resistor" of .05 ohms followed by another resistor of say 1K. There's 1A flowing. The voltage drop across the current sense resistor is aprox 100 mV. Accordingly, V= IR and P=VI. How come the current sense resistor only requires small wattage and other resistors require a greater wattage? I understand the equations etc. I'm trying to see this from an energy stand point.

I.e, is it because the small voltage across the current sense resistor means the current doesn't require much energy to go from one potential to another whereas in the large resistor the potential to ground is much greater so more energy is required?

Where does the energy come from?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Voltage is 6V. There's a "current sense resistor" of .05 ohms followed by another resistor of say 1K. There's 1A flowing.

This is not consistent. If you apply 6 V to a total resistance of 1000.05 ohms, you'll have a current of about 6 mA.

If you want to have 1 A flowing, you need to apply about 1000 V, not 6 V.

I'll assume you've adjusted the voltage value to achieve 1 A through the resistors.

> The voltage drop across the current sense resistor is aprox 100 mV.

You just said the current was 1 A, and the sense resistor value was 0.05 ohms.
If you apply Ohm's law, you can find the voltage drop across the sense resistor easily. It is not particularly close to 100 mV.

> How come the current sense resistor only requires small wattage and other resistors require a greater wattage?

For a resistor, you have $V=IR$. Combine that with your equation $P=IV$, and you have $P=I^2R$.

Since the current is 1 A for both the 1 kohm resistor and the 0.05 ohm resistor, you can now calculate that the power dissipated by the 1 kohm resistor is 1 kW, and the power dissipated by the 0.05 ohm resistor is 50 mW.

> Where does the energy come from?

The energy comes from whatever power source is forcing current to flow through the resistors.